# Embedding a font file (otf) into a Powershell forms script

Tags: forms, powershell, fonts, embed

I'm trying to embed a seven segment font into my script. So I tried to use the same way like embedding an icon for the forms title but it don't work. I think I need to use another command instead of [System.Drawing.Font] or am I completely wrong?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$fontBase64      = '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'
$fontBytes       = [Convert]::FromBase64String($fontBase64)
$stream          = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($fontBytes, 0, $fontBytes.Length)
$stream.Write($fontBytes, 0, $fontBytes.Length);
$font       = [System.Drawing.Font]::FromStream($stream, $true)

$Form               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.SuspendLayout()
$Form.Size          = "330,150"
$Form.AutoSize      = $false
$Form.Text          = "Font Test"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = "10,10"
$Label.Text = "123"
$Label.Font     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font,12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `([System.Drawing.Font].GetMethods()|Where-Object IsStatic).Name` does not contain `FromStream`. Run `[System.Drawing.Font]::new` to get `OverloadDefinitions`. See [system.drawing.font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=net-5.0#methods) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, embedding a font in a form is not the same as [embedding an icon to use as form icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377253/9898643).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$fontBase64 = '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'
$fontBytes  = [Convert]::FromBase64String($fontBase64)

# create an unsafe memory block for the font data and get a pointer to it
$fontPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocCoTaskMem($fontBytes.Count)

# copy the bytes to that unsafe memory block
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($fontBytes, 0, $fontPtr, $fontBytes.Count)

# create a PrivateFontCollection object
$privateFonts = [System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection]::new()

# add the font to the font collection
$privateFonts.AddMemoryFont($fontPtr, $fontBytes.Count)

# free the unsafe memory block
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeCoTaskMem($fontPtr)

# get the new font in a variable
$myFont = [System.Drawing.Font]::new($privateFonts.Families[0],12)


$Form               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size          = "330,150"
$Form.Text          = "Font Test"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = "10,10"
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$Label.Text = "0123456789"
$Label.Font     = $myFont
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$Form.ShowDialog()

# clean-up
$Form.Dispose()
```

[image]

Comment: After @JosefZ ansered I tried a little bit with 
```[System.Drawing.Font]::new()```
But I didn't knew these steps about allocating the memory before using the base64 converted font. So thank you very much!