# OpenFileDialog in PowerShell - Can the icon of the dialog be changed?

Tags: powershell

I have this code that will invoke the [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0) class.

There doesn't seem to be a property to change the icon of the dialog that's shown at the top left corner of the dialog.

Is there a way to hack a change this?

### Here's the code:

```
Function Invoke-OpenFileDialog {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [string] $Title,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $InitialDirectory,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] [string] $Filter
    )

  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

  if ($InitialDirectory -ne "") {
    if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $InitialDirectory -PathType Container)) {
      $InitialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$InitialDirectory).DirectoryName
    }
  }

  $OpenFileDialog                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.Filter           = $Filter
  $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.Title            = $Title
  $result                          = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
  $OpenFileDialog.Dispose()

  if ($result -eq 'OK') {
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
  }
  else { return "" }

}

$title = 'OpenFileDialog Title'
$initialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\").DirectoryName
$filter = 'All files (*.*)| *.*'

$filePicked = Invoke-OpenFileDialog -Title $title -InitialDirectory $initialDirectory -Filter $filter

# Then use this to check if the picker has done its job.
if ($filePicked -ne "") {
  $filePicked
  Write-Host 'File Picked...'
}
else {
  Write-Host 'File Not Picked...'
}
```

### The icon in question:

[image]

Comment: Running your code, I don't have an icon there in the OpenFileDialog window... My guess is that you are looking at the default icon displayed when opening your own form. That icon can be changed using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377253/9898643)

Comment: That's strange, I'm using that method for the `$form.icon` but that doesn't affect what the icon is in this dialog.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? For me (Win10) there is no icon on the OpenFile dialog...

Comment: Windows 10 Pro (Build 19042)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to set the icon independently from any UI by setting up:

`$OpenFileDialogForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form`

and passing a base64 string to the `icon` property of the `$OpenFileDialogForm`.

Then pass the `$OpenFileDialogForm` to:

`$userClicked = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($OpenFileDialogForm)`,

Some comments in the `Invoke-OpenFileDialog` function explaining this.

The `IconBase64` parameter in the function is where this can be set.

### Here's the code for this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Function Get-LastValidDirectory {

  Param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'The literal path where the folder you want to check is, which will return the last valid folder.')]
    [Array]$LiteralPath
    )

  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -PathType Container) {
    # Returns the path passed to the function if it has been found.'
    return $LiteralPath
  }

  # Increment the input folder
  $lastDir = Split-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath

  # Test that folder for it not existing and check if it's doesn't exist and in the
  # while loop increment the $lastDir variable.
  while (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $lastDir -PathType Container)) {
    $lastDir = Split-Path -LiteralPath $lastDir
  }

  return $lastDir

}

function Invoke-OpenFileDialog {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [string] $Title,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $InitialDirectory,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] [string] $Filter,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)] [string] $IconBase64,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4)] [boolean] $TopMost
    )

  if ($InitialDirectory -ne "") {
    if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $InitialDirectory -PathType Container)) {
      $InitialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$InitialDirectory).DirectoryName
    }
  }

  # Create a streaming image by streaming the base64 string to a bitmap stream source.

  $IconBase64 = $IconBase64
  $iconBytes  = [Convert]::FromBase64String($IconBase64)
  $stream     = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)
  $stream.Write($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)

  # Create a new form to hold the object and set it properties for the main
  # OpenFileDialog form.

  $OpenFileDialogForm         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $OpenFileDialogForm.Icon    = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle((New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap -Argument $stream).GetHIcon())
  $OpenFileDialogForm.TopMost = $TopMost

  # Set the properties of the main OpenFileDialog along with using the
  # OpenFileDialogForm properties from above.

  $OpenFileDialog                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.Filter           = $Filter
  $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.Title            = $Title
  $userClicked                     = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($OpenFileDialogForm)
  $OpenFileDialog.Dispose()

  if ($userClicked -eq 'OK') { return $OpenFileDialog.FileName } else { return "" }

}

$title = 'OpenFileDialog Title'
$initialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\").DirectoryName + '\no folder here'
$filter = 'Application (*.exe)|*.exe|SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'
$filter = 'All files (*.*)| *.*'
$iconBase64OpenFileDialog = "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"

$filePicked = Invoke-OpenFileDialog -Title $title -InitialDirectory $initialDirectory -Filter $filter -IconBase64 $iconBase64OpenFileDialog -TopMost $true

# Then use this to check if the picker has done its job.
if ($filePicked -ne "") {
  $filePicked
  Write-Host 'File Picked...'
}
else {
  Write-Host 'File Not Picked...'
}
```

Comment: ..But That is just the same as my code, where you set the icon to the FORM and because of that, the OpenFile dialog gets that same icon.. you just swapped the lines around and now create a form in the function, where my code did that outside that function. Sorry, but that is not adding an icon to the dialog _"independent of a UI"_ as you put it.

Comment: It really is. The icon can be different to that of the main form. Plus it works for both WinForm and WPF.

Comment: Nope, your claim it can _"set the icon independently from any UI"_ is false. It is the FORM's icon that is used by the OpenFileDialog. You can create multiple forms and give each of them a different icon, but it is still the icon of the form (if any) that is used by the dialog.  
This is nothing but a replica of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228194/9898643), where I have demonstrated this icon dependency. All you did is wrap that code into a function..

Comment: Exactly the function allows this and the parent form in the UI has no visible UI. Yours did. Its not a replica at all. Your answer doesn't work for all cases. It involved two different methods for WinForm and WPF. How can my function be identical if it works for both, because it's not.

Comment: Again.. disagree. Your function uses a **Windows.Forms.Form** to do the trick just as my first answer did. It has nothing to do with how you create your other windows. My second answer was an answer to your first comment and shows how you can embed an icon in a WPF window and have the dialog use that.

Comment: My approach, which is different uses a WinForm for the parent form of the dialog regardless of whether the main form is WPF or a WinForm. I agree the basic approach is the same but the method in doing so is different and is exactly what I was after. And the function can be used in both cases very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Create your form and use my code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377253/9898643) to give that form your own icon.

Then, from a button for example on the form, you open the OpenFile dialog, using your function. The dialog will then have the icon used in your form.

```
# start the code with your own function to show the OpenFile dialog
function Invoke-OpenFileDialog {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [string] $Title,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $InitialDirectory,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] [string] $Filter
    )

  if ($InitialDirectory -ne "") {
    if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $InitialDirectory -PathType Container)) {
      $InitialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$InitialDirectory).DirectoryName
    }
  }

  $OpenFileDialog                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.Filter           = $Filter
  $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.Title            = $Title
  $result                          = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
  $OpenFileDialog.Dispose()

  if ($result -eq 'OK') {
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
  }
  else { return "" }

}

# next, create your form (just a simple demo below) and from there show the dialog
# (I'm using a button on the form to do this)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = '400,230'
$form.text       = "Test"
$form.TopMost    = $false

# This base64 string holds the bytes that make up the 16x16 StackOverflow icon
$iconBase64 = @'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'@

$iconBytes       = [Convert]::FromBase64String($iconBase64)
$stream          = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)
$stream.Write($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)
$form.Icon       = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle((New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap -Argument $stream).GetHIcon())

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,24)
$button.Left = $form.Width - $button.Width - 40
$button.Top = $form.Height - $button.Height * 3
$button.Text = 'Open File'
$button.Add_Click({
    # in here, we use your function
    $title = 'OpenFileDialog Title'
    $initialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\").DirectoryName
    $filter = 'All files (*.*)| *.*'
    $filePicked = Invoke-OpenFileDialog -Title $title -InitialDirectory $initialDirectory -Filter $filter

    # Then use this to check if the picker has done its job.
    if ($filePicked -ne "") {
      $filePicked
      Write-Host 'File Picked...'
    }
    else {
      Write-Host 'File Not Picked...'
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($button)

[void]$form.ShowDialog()

# when done, dispose of the form
$form.Dispose()
```

Now, if you run this, you'll see the form:

[image]

and if you click the button, the dialog shows up, including your forms icon:

[image]

---

You can do this for a WPF UI aswell, although setting a WPF form with an embedded icon is slightly different:

```
# start the code with your own function to show the OpenFile dialog
function Invoke-OpenFileDialog {
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [string] $Title,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $InitialDirectory,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] [string] $Filter
    )

    if ($InitialDirectory -ne "") {
        if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $InitialDirectory -PathType Container)) {
            $InitialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$InitialDirectory).DirectoryName
        }
    }

    $OpenFileDialog                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.Filter           = $Filter
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.Title            = $Title
    $result                          = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.Dispose()

    if ($result -eq 'OK') {
        return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    }
    else { return "" }
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    Width = "400" Height = "230" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
    <Button x:Name = "Button" Height = "24" Width = "90" Content = 'Open File' />
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

# This base64 string holds the bytes that make up the 16x16 StackOverflow icon
$iconBase64 = @'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'@

$iconBytes  = [Convert]::FromBase64String($iconBase64)
$stream     = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)
$stream.Write($iconBytes, 0, $iconBytes.Length)
# set the form's icon
$Window.Icon = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame]::Create($stream)

# connect to the button
$button = $Window.FindName("Button")
$button.Add_Click({
    # in here, we use your function
    $title = 'OpenFileDialog Title'
    $initialDirectory = ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\").DirectoryName
    $filter = 'All files (*.*)| *.*'
    $filePicked = Invoke-OpenFileDialog -Title $title -InitialDirectory $initialDirectory -Filter $filter

    # Then use this to check if the picker has done its job.
    if ($filePicked -ne "") {
        $filePicked
        Write-Host 'File Picked...'
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'File Not Picked...'
    }
})

$null = $Window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks, Theo. In not knowing if this was associated with the form I didn't mention that it's a WPF UI I'm using as I thought it was unrelated. This does in fact work for a WinForm. Unfortunately, I forget to mention the WPF part. I tried to implement this into a simple WPF UI but cannot get it to work. I'll mark this as answered seeing as it answers my initial question.

Comment: @Ste I have added demo code to have this work for a WPF UI too. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much for that ammendment Theo!

Comment: I found a way to add an icon independently from a WinForm or WPF one. I've added an answer to show this which doesn't even have a form. Just the `OpenFileDialog`.