# how would i download and use an icon in powershell

Tags: image, powershell, icons, shortcut, favicon

whenever i download and use an ico file in powershell it always throws me an error saying "FILEPATH" contains no icons even though it has selected an ico file this is the code i got

```
$url = "WEBSITE FAVICON URL"
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile C:\Windows\temp\test.ico

$path = "path"
New-Item .\Desktop -ItemType Directory -Force

$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
  $lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut($desktop+"\LINKNAME.lnk")
  $lnk.IconLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\test.ico"
  $lnk.TargetPath = "MY WEBSITE URL"
  $lnk.Save()
```

and when i run this with the caps filled in then the shortcut has a blank icon and when i try and change it in properties i get thrown this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aclrn.png), is there any way anybody knows how to download and use a icon for a shortcut in a PowerShell terminal?

Comment: [1] please provide a real [and reachable by others] URL to test with. ///// [2] downloads are often marked as `blocked` ... is the file you dl'd blocked? if so, what happens when you unblock it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed an icon in a PowerShell GUI executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376491/how-to-embed-an-icon-in-a-powershell-gui-executable)

Comment: The normal extension for a WebSite shortcut is `.url`, not `.lnk` which has different properties: `.URL`, `.IconIndex` and `.IconFile`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the URL for the favicon is indeed pointing to an icon file and you download it using

```
$iconPath = 'C:\Windows\temp\test.ico'
# for demo I'm using the icon from stackoverflow.com
$url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $iconPath
```

You then want to create an Internet shortcut (.url) which has different properties than a shortcut to a file or path (.lnk):

```
$shortcutName = 'Stack OverFlow'
$shortcutPath = Join-Path -Path ([environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath ($shortcutName + '.url')
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)
# for a .url shortcut only set the TargetPath here
$shortcut.TargetPath = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
$shortcut.Save()

# create a Here-String with the .url specific properties (in Name=Value format)
$urlProps = @"
Hotkey=0
IconFile=$iconPath
IconIndex=0
"@
# and add that to the newly created shortcut file
Add-Content -Path $shortcutPath -Value $urlProps

# clean up the COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WshShell) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

---

If you want to see what is in the shortcut file, you can do

```
Get-Content $shortcutPath
```

where you will find it is just a text file in INI format:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,11
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
URL=https://stackoverflow.com/
Hotkey=0
IconFile=C:\Windows\temp\test.ico
IconIndex=0
```

where property `TargetPath` is now called `URL`