# How do I set an icon in PoshGUI that is in the internet? (PoshGUI WinForms)

Tags: powershell

So well, I'm making a Pull Request for [Chris Titus Tech's Ultimate Windows Toolbox](https://www.github.com/christitustech/win10script)

And I'm making another form called More, and I'm using another file for it, so I decided to start using PoshGUI, and I need to set the icon to the icon, and I tried, but I just can't find anything, even in the Documentation!

Here is one, which I used base64:

```
SetValueInvocationException: C:\Users\fgclue\test.ps1:15
Line |
  15 |  $MainForm.icon                   = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcwAAAHMC …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "icon": "Cannot convert value
     | "Base64"
```

I also tried using the URL:

```
Line |
  15 |  $MainForm.icon                   = "https://avatars.githubusercontent …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "icon": "Cannot convert value "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/7896101?v=4"
     | to type "System.Drawing.Icon". Error: "A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo
     | do volume está incorreta. : 'C:\Users\fgclue\https:\avatars.githubusercontent.com\u\7896101?v=4'""
```

A bit of the error is in portuguese (As that is the language my computer is in), so I translated it:

```
Error: "The syntax of the name of the directory or of the file
         | The volume is incorrect. :
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here is a ScreenShot
[image: ScreenShot]

Edit 2: Here's my code:

```
<# 
.NAME
    WinForm
.SYNOPSIS
    A form
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$MainForm                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$MainForm.ClientSize             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$MainForm.text                   = "More"
$MainForm.TopMost                = $false
$MainForm.icon                   = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/7896101?v=4"



#region Logic 

#endregion

[void]$MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Believe it's looking for a .ico

Comment: I'm going to convert it an see if it works.

Comment: Turns out it didn't work.

Comment: `$MainForm.icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\scripts\icon.ico')` how about this?

Comment: It does! Thanks!

Comment: You can embed the icon as base64. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377253/9898643)